# How to override 2 (two) packages in Nixos configuration.nix

Tags: nix, nixos

I have some package to override in my configuration.nix. So I write the code as follows:

```
nixpkgs.config = {
  allowUnfree = true;
  packageOverrides = {
    pkgs: rec {
      #mumble + pulse audio
      mumble = pkgs.mumble.override {
        pulseSupport = true;
      };

      #kernel for intel ethernet and Testing e1000e package override
      linuxPackages.e1000e = pkgs.linuxPackages.e1000e.overrideDerivation (attrs: {
        name = "e1000e-3.3.3-${config.boot.kernelPackages.kernel.version}";
        src = fetchurl {
          url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxx883hx9763ygn/e1000e-3.3.3.tar.gz?dl=0";
          sha256 = "1s2w54927fsxg0f037h31g3qkajgn5jd0x3yi1chxsyckrcr0x80";
        };
      });
    };
  };
};
```

but when I do `nixos-rebuild switch`, I got the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '.' or '=', at 37,11
```

which is at `pkgs: rec {...`

What did I do wrong? At first I write it by separating the pkgs like this:

```
packageOverrides = {
  pkgs: with pkgs: {......}; #this is for mumble
  pkgs: rec {...}; #this is for kernel
};
```

and still got the same error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proper solution is:

```
nixpkgs.config = {

  allowUnfree = true;

  packageOverrides = super: let self = super.pkgs; in {

    mumble = super.mumble.override { pulseSupport = true; };

    linuxPackages = super.linuxPackages // {
      e1000e = super.linuxPackages.e1000e.overrideDerivation (old: {
        name = "e1000e-3.3.3-${config.boot.kernelPackages.kernel.version}";
        src = fetchurl {
          url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxx883hx9763ygn/e1000e-3.3.3.tar.gz?dl=0";
          sha256 = "1s2w54927fsxg0f037h31g3qkajgn5jd0x3yi1chxsyckrcr0x80";
        };
      });
    };
  };
}
```

The variable `super` refers to the Nixpkgs set *before* the overrides are applied and `self` refers to it *after* the overrides are applied. It's important to distinguish these two explicitly to avoid infinite recursions, etc.

Also, note that your override

> linuxPackages.e1000e = pkgs.linuxPackages.e1000e.overrideDerivation ...

replaces the `linuxPackages` attribute set with one that contains nothing but the (overriden) `e1000e` derivation. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: It doesn't look like `self`, introduced by the let binding, ever gets used. Is it even necessary in this situation?

Comment: The `self` binding is unnecessary, indeed. I added it to the example by habit, mostly, because oftentimes one does need it.

Comment: regarding your comment "Also note... ", what's the right way to do it?

Comment: should this nowadays be solved via overlays? Whats the difference between `packageOverrides` and using an overlay?

Comment: @MarcDefiant To **question1**: Yes, it can be, but [`packageOverrides` are not officially deprecated yet](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/43266). The linked issue also has comments regarding use cases that may still hold true. To **question2**: Couldn't find much but hopefully the deprecation RFC will shed a light on it - once ready..:)