# Using stack 1.8.0 (the current `stack upgrade --git`) in NixOS?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix, nixos

How does one obtain Stack `1.8.*` on NixOS? In general, how does one ensure that the version of `stack` running on NixOS is the equivalent of the version that would run with `stack update --git` on a non-NixOS machine?

Answer (score 3):

In Nix, if you want to have a specific version of a package, you create a derivation for it.

### Derivation

To create the derivation for Stack, you can get one of the pre-built [Stack releases](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases) using the `nix-prefetch-scripts` package and `stdenv.mkDerivation` as it is shown [here](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-using-stdenv).

Stack 1.8 seems not released yet, so you need to build it from sources. One way to do it is `cabal2nix`:

```
cabal2nix --shell 'https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack.git' > stack.nix
```

There are more examples in the [manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#how-to-create-nix-builds-for-your-own-private-haskell-packages)

## nixpkgs

Now you have the derivation with the right version of the software. If you want it to be the system-default, you [override your Nixpkgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000514/how-to-override-2-two-packages-in-nixos-configuration-nix).

Here is the example from the [docs](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-modify-via-packageOverrides):

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    stack = ./path/to/stack.nix {};
  };
}
```

### Update

We've found that the derivation produced by `cabal2nix` doesn't work in the case of stack because `haskellPackages` are missing some of the dependencies.

Here I've created [gist](https://gist.github.com/4e6/fb9749f4cc439086da0667ec0a892f3d) with the (slightly adapted) result of running `stackage2nix` on the stack repo. The result of `default.nix` is not a single derivation but a set of packages required to build the stack. So the override for your system should look like:

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    stack = (import ./default.nix {}).stack;
  };
}
```

Comment: I successfully generated the `stack.nix`, but it's still opaque to me how to link to it in my `configuration.nix` via a package override (I read your link). Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Here is the docs https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-modify-via-packageOverrides. You need to override stack attribute: `stack = import /path/to/stack.nix {};`. Relative path should also work

Comment: I'm getting this error: `error: 'f' at /home/george/.dotfiles/nixos/stack.nix:7:7 called without required argument 'githash', at /nix/store/a55hr4k99fdn5lxym8ba8545lndabwfk-nixos-18.03.132847.aec217852f2/nixos/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:88:27
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)`

Comment: It is the issue with `cabal2nix`, I'm getting the same error. I'm looking into it

Comment: Oh, there's no `githash` package in the `haskellPackages` of nixpkgs. So we have the problem with derivation. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @George, I've made a custom derivation for Stack, check the updated answer

Comment: @436: I now get "error: attribute 'stackage' missing" on line 409.

Comment: Oh, it requires the stackage overlay installed. Sorry, completely forgot to mention. This one https://github.com/typeable/nixpkgs-stackage

Comment: The installation instructions on `nixpkgs-stackage` are somewhat opaque. In this context, do you know how I would install it in my NixOS machine?

Comment: I updated the gist. Now you don't need to install the overlay, derivation will do it for you.

Comment: @436: Thanks for the updated gist. I now get error "Could not find module ‘Conduit’" after lots of compiling.

Comment: Can you please provide the full error message, I need some context. We can also move this conversation to the GitHub. Gist comments should be a better place to post the code snippets.

Comment: I'm in need of something like this again for Stack 1.10. Do you know how one can generalize your solution into a script or something that can make it reproducible for all new future stack builds?

Comment: @George you can open an issue on typeable/stackage2nix repo, but I can't promise that I will have time to look into it soon.